# Erro ao baixar branch no git

Tags: git, branch

Estava trabalhando numa branch na minha máquina pessoal, e quando fui baixá-la na máquina da empresa, usando o power shell do windows, recebi a seguinte mensagem:

```
PS projeto> git checkout -t origin/minha_branch
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'minha_branch' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/minha_branch' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você deu clone em um projeto e está trocando de branch, você pode só utilizar `git checkout <branch>` sem precisar do `-t`, porque o git vai automaticamente buscar as referências e gerenciar o tracking.

Se isso continuar acontecendo, veja se seus remotes estão corretos com o `git remote -v` e tente utilizar o `git fetch <seuRemote>` e `git remote update <seuremote>` para atualizar as referências, depois use o mesmo comando novamente.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945654/git-checkout-updating-paths-is-incompatible-with-switching-branches

http://dianaarnos.com/pt/git-resolvendo-erro-cannot-update-paths/